# How to search for term in query using elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know the proper format or way to [search for term in query](http://search%20for%20term%20in%20query) using elasticsearch
in URl method for example

```
http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search?q=category:الأنظمة&size=100&sort=date:desc&default_operator=AND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put your query in the request body?

```
GET http://localhost:9200/ncar_index/ncar/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {"date": "desc"}
    ],
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "category": {
                "query": "الأنظمة",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Reference documents*
[Match Query doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)
[Limit result with From/Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8//search-request-from-size.html)
[Sorting search result](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html)